# How to get selected option ID with Javascript not JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, select

I need to print the selected option ID with Javascript not JQuery for both select tags.

Assume we have more than one select tags.

```
<select  onchange="showOptions(this)" id="my_select1">
   <option value="a1" id="ida1">Option1</option>
   <option value="a2" id="ida2">Option2</option>
</select>

<select  onchange="showOptions(this)" id="my_select2">
   <option value="b1" id="idb1">Option1</option>
   <option value="b2" id="idb2">Option2</option>
</select>
```

I found out the following way `options[selectedIndex].id` but how can I know to which one of those that line refers to..

Any suggestions?

I Tried the following but it did not work.

```
<select id="my_select" onchange="showOptions2(this)">
   <option value="o1" id="id1">Option1</option>
   <option value="o2" id="id2">Option2</option>
</select>


<script type = "text/javascript">


function showOptions2(s){
 var adVALUE = console.log(s[s.selectedIndex].value); // get value
 var adID = console.log(s[s.selectedIndex].id); // get id

  alert(adID);

}
</script>
```

Comment: How can you know which one of those that line refers to? What? You put that code wherever you want to find the `id`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
<select onchange="showOptions(this)">
   ...
```

---

this function will do the work

```
function showOptions(s) {
  console.log(s[s.selectedIndex].value); // get value
  console.log(s[s.selectedIndex].id); // get id
}
```

Note that, unless you are using them for other purpose, you may omit the `id` on `select` elements

Example jsbin : http://jsbin.com/adopiz/2/edit

Comment: Then I delete my original comment, and offer a +1! =)

Comment: I updated my question and I added what I tried based on Fabrizio's answer but it did not work.

Comment: I did open the jsbin and it seems that when I am trying to alert the returned id value it says undefined again.

Comment: george the example works fine: http://jsbin.com/adopiz/4/edit this shows an alert with the id on change event