# Getting diffrent forms on different options

Tags: javascript

I am trying to show each form when an option is selected, but i cant even alert the id's of every option xD.....

```
    <select id="contactOptions" class="pad10 col100 mart25" name="level">
        <option class="" selected disabled>About</option>
        <option data-option="option01" class="" value="1">Form01</option>
        <option data-option="option02" class="" value="2">Form02</option>
        <option data-option="option03" class="" value="3">Form03</option>
        <option data-option="option04" class="" value="4">Form04</option>
    </select>

<form action="#" method="POST" id="option01">
</form>

<form action="#" method="POST" id="option02">
</form>

<form action="#" method="POST" id="option03">
</form>

<form action="#" method="POST" id="option04">
</form>
```

I am trying to target the parent and alert the ID's, but it only alert the parent id's? can anyone help me on to only make a click event on option01,02,03,04 ? not the default but only the four options?

```
var contactOptions = document.querySelector("#contactOptions");
contactOptions.addEventListener("click", doSomethings, false);

function doSomethings(e){
    alert(e.target.id);
}
```

Related links but with inline js

[link01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625516/how-to-get-selected-option-id-with-javascript-not-jquery)

Comment: The question is quite confusing the way it is asked. Can you rephrase it, I'm not able to understand what you're asking

Comment: Use the `change` event instead of `click`. That way it is more reliable. And also use `e.target.value` for getting the value of the selected option.

Comment: The .value works but .id does not? it takes the parent id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use the `change` event for a more reliable behavior
- Get the selected index with `e.target.selectedIndex`
- Get the `data-` property with `.dataset.option` (the property to access is "option" because the "data-" gets trimmed internally)
- Create a new function in order to hide all forms and then show the one with the `id` based on the chosen option of the `select`

  - For hiding all forms I used `.querySelectorAll` that has `.forEach` method that allows me to iterate over the elements easily
- Here I used CSS in order to hide all forms by default, and then show one by using inline style, you could create a CSS class that changes the `display` property and then toggle it with JavaScript

```js
var contactOptions = document.querySelector("#contactOptions");
contactOptions.addEventListener("change", doSomethings, false);

function doSomethings(e) {
  var selectedIndex = e.target.selectedIndex;
  var selectedFormId = e.target.options[selectedIndex].dataset.option;
  showSelectedForm(selectedFormId)
}

function showSelectedForm(id) {  
  // hide other forms
  document.querySelectorAll('form').forEach(function(element) {
    element.style.display = 'none';
  });
  
  var formToShow = document.querySelector('form#' + id);
  
  // show the selected form
  formToShow.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
form {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="contactOptions" class="pad10 col100 mart25" name="level">
    <option class="" selected disabled>About</option>
    <option data-option="option01" class="" value="1">Form01</option>
    <option data-option="option02" class="" value="2">Form02</option>
    <option data-option="option03" class="" value="3">Form03</option>
    <option data-option="option04" class="" value="4">Form04</option>
</select>

<form action="#" method="POST" id="option01">
  form option01
</form>

<form action="#" method="POST" id="option02">
  form option02
</form>

<form action="#" method="POST" id="option03">
  form option03
</form>

<form action="#" method="POST" id="option04">
  form option04
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

[onchange](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) of the options call a function that with hide and display the correct form.

```js
function showForm() {
    var option = document.getElementById('contactOptions').value;
    switch (option) {
        case '1':
            displayForm('option01');
            break;
        case '2':
            displayForm('option02');
            break;
        case '3':
            displayForm('option03');
            break;
        case '4':
            displayForm('option04');
    }
}

function displayForm(id) {
    var formsCollection = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
    for (var i = 0; i < formsCollection.length; i++) {
        if (formsCollection[i].id != id) {
            formsCollection[i].style.display = 'none';
        }else {
            formsCollection[i].style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
}
```

```css
form {
        display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="contactOptions" onchange="showForm()" class="pad10 col100 mart25" name="level">
    <option class="" selected disabled>About</option>
    <option data-option="option01" class="" value="1">Form01</option>
    <option data-option="option02" class="" value="2">Form02</option>
    <option data-option="option03" class="" value="3">Form03</option>
    <option data-option="option04" class="" value="4">Form04</option>
</select>

<form action="#" method="POST" id="option01">
    <input value="form 1" type="text">
</form>

<form action="#" method="POST" id="option02">
    <input value="form 2" type="text">
</form>

<form action="#" method="POST" id="option03">
    <input value="form 3" type="text">
</form>

<form action="#" method="POST" id="option04">
    <input value="form 4" type="text">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

- When load the html,call a function to hide all the form in the page. e.g I used `onload=hideAllForm();`
- After selecting from drop-down get `data-option` attribute value.
- Show the form by id, selected by user.

```html
<script>
function hideAllForm(){
var formLength = document.getElementsByTagName('form').length;
for(var i=0;i<formLength;i++){
    document.getElementsByTagName('form')[i].style.display="none";
  }
}


function _check(){
    var formLength = document.getElementsByTagName('form').length;
    var e = document.getElementById("contactOptions");
    var id = e.options[e.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-option');
 for(var i=0;i<formLength;i++){
     document.getElementsByTagName('form')[i].style.display="none";
 }
 document.getElementById(id).style.display="block";
 }
</script>

<body onload="hideAllForm();">

<select id="contactOptions" class="pad10 col100 mart25" onchange="_check();" name="level">
        <option class="" selected disabled>About</option>
        <option data-option="option01" class="" value="1">Form01</option>
        <option data-option="option02" class="" value="2">Form02</option>
        <option data-option="option03" class="" value="3">Form03</option>
        <option data-option="option04" class="" value="4">Form04</option>
    </select>

<form action="#" method="POST" id="option01">
form01
</form>

<form action="#" method="POST" id="option02">
form02
</form>

<form action="#" method="POST" id="option03">
form03
</form>

<form action="#" method="POST" id="option04">
form04
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: The question doesn't have `jQuery` tag

Comment: Sorry this is not a jQuery question :) thanks for the answer anyway

Comment: @julekgwa before downvote, you should read the link https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130046/when-should-i-vote