# How to get selected option in React.js not jQuery or any other framework?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I used the way that in the page ([get selected option id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625516/how-to-get-selected-option-id-with-javascript-not-jquery)) mentioned, but in React.js I struggled in this way but `this`  is undefined. How do I get the id of the selected option?

```
<select id="my_select" onchange={() => handleChange(this)}>
   <option value="o1" id="id1">Option1</option>
   <option value="o2" id="id2">Option2</option>
</select>
```

And here is my `onChange()` function:

```
const handleChange = (obj) => {
    console.log("What is this?", obj); // --> undefined

};
```

How do I get the id of the selected option?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, keep in mind you can pass `this` keyword as a parameter to your function. like this (also there is a typo in your provided code where the `onchage` should be `onChange` as you use react elements here):

```js
<select id="my_select" onChange={() => handleChange(this)}>
   ...
</select>
```

But you can't use `this` keyword as your input param in your actual function.

```js
const handleChange = (this) => { // This will throw an error (Binding invalid left-hand side ...)
  ...
};
```

So you should use the access the provided `this` keyword in your actual function just like this:

```js
const handleChange = (param) => {
  console.log("What is this?", param); // Represent the window element
};
```

### Does this give us the select option value?

The short answer is **no**, but why?

Since **we're defining the `handleChange` function in our global scope** (and also declared arrow functions for both `onChange` and `handleChange`) **it will give us the actual `window` element** which is not useful for getting the `select` value.

---

### What is the best way to do it then?

To get the actual value of the selected option you can do it simply by using `event` interface just like this:

```js
<select id="my_select" onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}>
   ...
</select>

const handleChange = (event) => {
   console.log("What is this?", event.target.value); // Represent the actual value of selected option
};
```

**NOTE:** You can read more about `event` interface [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).

---

### UPDATE

As you wanted to access the selected option id you can simply achieve that by using `event.target.selectedOptions` property which provides a list of whole selected option elements just like this:

```js
const handleChange = (event) => {
   console.log("What is this?", event.target.selectedOptions[0].id); // Represent the actual id of selected option
};
```

**NOTE:** Since the `event.target.selectedOptions` will provide an array of items so you should access the first one by using `event.target.selectedOptions[0]` and get the attribute that you wanted simply by dot notation.

Comment: I want to get the id of the selected option not the value of a select tag.

Comment: @s.hesam check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions (so `event.target.selectedOptions[0].id`)

Comment: @s.hesam As @arieljuod said you can simply do that by accessing `event.target.selectedOptions` which provide the selected option element.